# How to export a large dataset from R to CSV?

Tags: r, csv

I have a R data frame with 20,000 observations and 2100 variables, how do I export it to CSV format. I used write.table as follows

```
write.table(a,"Lucas1",sep=",",row.names=FALSE);
```

where a is the dataset. Lucas1 is the name of the file in which I want to store the data. I got following error

```
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I am a beginner in R, can anyone suggest me an easy solution to this problem?

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use

```
write.csv(a, "Lucas1.csv", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Come on, where is the similar option in `data.table`?

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at `write_csv` in the new `readr` package.  I would imagine it would be quicker than `utils::write.csv`.  As an added bonus, you no longer need to specify `row.names = FALSE`

```
write_csv(a, "Lucas1.csv")
```