# Options for printing R output?

Tags: r

I am running a very time consuming chunk of code that will give an output that exceeds maxprint. I would like to be able to access the output at a later date without re-running the code.

I know there are many ways to do this, but it there a simple (one to two lines) way to do it? I would like to be able to just save the output as a .csv or something similar.

Comment: Can you try to give us some kind of example of what you have tried?

Comment: Use `write.csv()` or save the object (`save()`) and load it (`load()`) when you need it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a large dataset from R to CSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34217169/how-to-export-a-large-dataset-from-r-to-csv)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your helpful reply @S Rivero.
I think the following will work well for me:

```
write.csv(MyData, file = "MyData.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: To the down voter: I would have found this a useful answer if I had come across it. Terribly sorry that it seems to be beneath you.